# How to type a generic function that uses Array.push()?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

While working on generics:

```
function newArr<T>(arr: T[], itemToAdd: string): T[] {
  return arr.push(itemToAdd);
}

const arr: string[] = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"];

const itemToAdd: string = "item 4";

newArr<string>(arr, itemToAdd);
```

I've bumped into this error when I hover over `itemToAdd`.

[image: code snippet]

```
Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
  'number' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.
```

What would be the best way to sort this out with a decent type safety?

Comment: The function parameter should be `itemToAdd: T`.

Comment: I've tried but I get the error `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T[]'`

Comment: That's because of the *return* type, `.push` doesn't return the array. Also you shouldn't need to explicitly supply the generic type because it can be inferred from the arguments.

Comment: Either use `.concat` to return a *new* array that has the `itemToAdd` appended to the end, or do `arr.push(itemToAdd); return arr;`. The `.push` method always returns the new length of the array, so you cannot use its return value as `T[]`.

Comment: I've tried already a few of these suggestions but didn't work. I'll edit the question to include these. thanks

Comment: You haven't fixed the *first* error in any of those, `itemToAdd: T`. If this is only supposed to handle arrays of strings, you can remove the generic type entirely. The type for your current implementation would be `<T>(arr: T[], itemToAdd: T) => number`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you are right, I didn't. But it works now!. I'll update the correct answer. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer by doing:

```
function newArr<T>(arr: T[], itemToAdd: T): T[] {
  arr.push(itemToAdd);
  return arr;
}
```

I forgot to set `itemToAdd: T` and I was not returning the array.